# Possible to achieve a "cut" image look using only CSS3?

Tags: image, css

Referring to the kind of look of the images seen on this site - http://sl.dream-theme.com/html/albums-light.html (I'm in no way involved with this WP theme, just providing an example). The author is using jRaphael to create "path cuts" which is a nice and browser-safe approach, but I'd like to avoid including an additional library solely for that purpose.

Comment: with -webkit-mask, but the browser support is poor (non standard.)

Comment: Use the [clip property](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/clip_gallery.html#nogo) or [transparent borders](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/fivestar.html) to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very basic:

http://dabblet.com/gist/2874826

uses css pseudo elements to mask the image (pretty descent browser support -- will render as a square image in legacy browsers, probably nbd?)

If shadows / borders / things are needed you could add and additional wrapper to fake the slanted borders using more pseudo elements or a manipulated (transformed) box, or something.